# Could checkboxes such as "Notify" get an HTML label tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, usability

I tend to hate checkboxes without any `<label>`. Because basically that means that you have to click a 20×20 px² area to hit the checkbox. Making the texts "Notify" and "daily of any new answers" a `<label>` for the checkbox would allow you to click the text as well and not only on the tiny checkbox.

Comment: Good call, from a usability point of view...

Comment: This should be default behavior for every website. Just as long as the label isn't abnormally large with no indication of click area. Should be tight around the text.

Comment: Just for the record, Joey, I'd say @Cawas' edit was just fine and actually helpful. What made you write [that revision comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6166/revisions)?

Comment: Arjas: I value proper spelling. Hence my edit to their edit.

Comment: Joey what @Arjan meant was how you implied my edit was not useful on your comment. I'm fine with your edit as well. It improved over mine. And sorry for the bad spelling. I have a thing against uppercasing and sometimes I forget to proper do it in places where it's required. ;)

Comment: Indeed, somehow I erroneously interpreted that edit comment as implying that @Cawas' edit was no good at all. But that's not what you wrote, my bad. (Will be cleaning up these comments, some day.)

Comment: Definitely a good idea; both for accessibility and the increasing number of touch-devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a no-brainer to me. Which is a perfect fit for me!

Next deploy