# Add label to the »suggested edit was helpful« checkbox when improving pending edits

Tags: feature-request, usability

HTML has a handy `label` element that allows to associate text with a form control and in graphical user agents allows the user to give focus (or execute an action) on such a control by invoking the *label* with a pointing device, e.g. the mouse or a finger.

Not using it basically means that the user has to hit a tiny target of often just 16×16 px² which, as Fitts' law tells us, is worse than hitting a target of 300×16 px².

---

This is basically a conceptual duplicate of my older [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): *[Could checkboxes such as “Notify” get an HTML label tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/131358)*

Comment: `+2` for labels. `-1` for square pixels.

Comment: *Lengths are commonly given in pixels as well [...]* I know, but pixels are like city blocks, not meters. Square pixels measure volume in the 4th dimension. :-)  "Liters per km" is **not** an area, although the English usage of *per* makes it look like it. Here, *per* indicates division. "Liters *times* km" would be an area.

Comment: OK, you got me there.